# Код формирования SQL-запроса

Tags: php, sql

Товарищи, как бы получше переписать подобный говнокод?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users(login,pass,name,email) VALUES(
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login'])."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string(md5crypt($_POST['pass']))."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [PDO](http://ua.php.net/pdo)
или напишите свою библиотеку которая будет поддерживать плейcхолдеры, в итоге запрос будет иметь вид что-то вроде:

```
$query = query("INSERT INTO users(login,pass,name,email) VALUES( :l, :p, :n, :e )",
array(
':l' => $_POST['login'], ':p' => md5crypt($_POST['pass']), 
':n' => $_POST['name'], ':e' => $_POST['email']
)
);
```

или

```
$query = query("INSERT INTO users(login,pass,name,email) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",
array(
$_POST['login'], md5crypt($_POST['pass']), $_POST['name'], $_POST['email']
)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы уверены, что в $_POST ничего больше нет, кроме нужных полей, то (после предварительной обработки значений $_POST):

```
$_POST['pass'] = md5crypt($_POST['pass']);  
$query = "INSERT INTO users(".implode(",", array_keys($_POST)).") VALUES('".implode("','", array_values($_POST))."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users SET ";
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    $sql .= $key . " = '" . $value . "', ";
}
$sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql) - 2); // убираем последнюю запятую
```

Как-то так. За безопасностью следите сами)

Comment: тогда уж:

$sql = "INSERT INTO users SET ";
$cc = '';
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    $sql .= $cc . $key . " = '" . $value . "'";
    $cc = ', ';
}

Comment: Не нужно вставлять код в комментарии. Они не предназначены для этого.

Answer (score 0):

```
class DConnection extends DObject{
    private $MYSQL_SERVER;
    private $MYSQL_USERNAME;
    private $MYSQL_PASSWORD;
    private $MYSQL_DATABASE;
    function __construct($_SERVER,$_USERNAME,$_PASSWORD,$_DATABASE){
        $this->MYSQL_SERVER=$_SERVER;
        $this->MYSQL_USERNAME=$_USERNAME;
        $this->MYSQL_PASSWORD=$_PASSWORD;
        $this->MYSQL_DATABASE=$_DATABASE;
    }
    public function isConnected(){
        if($this->connection)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public function connect(){
        $this->connection=mysql_connect($this->MYSQL_SERVER,$this->MYSQL_USERNAME,$this->MYSQL_PASSWORD);
        if($this->connection){
            mysql_select_db($this->MYSQL_DATABASE,$this->connection);
            mysql_query('set names utf8',$this->connection);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function createQuery($sql){
        return new DQuery($this->connection,$sql);
    }
    public function close(){
        if($this->connection)
            return mysql_close($this->connection);
        else
            return true;
    } 
}
class DQuery extends DObject{
    protected $sql;
    protected $connection;
    protected $stmt;
    function __construct(&$connection,&$sql){
        $this->sql=$sql;
        $this->connection=$connection;
    }
    public function bind($ph_name,$variable){
        $this->sql=str_replace(':'.$ph_name,'"'.mysql_real_escape_string($variable,$this->connection).'"',$this->sql);
        return true;
    }
    public function execute(){
        return $this->stmt=mysql_query($this->sql,$this->connection);
    }
    public function fetch(){
        return mysql_fetch_array($this->stmt,MYSQL_ASSOC);
    }
    public function free(){
        return mysql_free_result($this->stmt);
    }
    public function getError(){
        return mysql_error($this->connection);
    }
    public function getLastId(){
        return mysql_insert_id($this->connection);
    }
}
```

Используйте самописный класс, так будет удобнее и приятнее читать код.
Ваш пример перепишется так:

```
$connection=new DConnection(...);
if($connection->connect()){
    $query=$connection->createQuery('INNSERT INTO users(login,pass,name,email) VALUES(:psLogin,md5(:psPass),:psName,:psEmail)'); 
    $query->bind('psLogin',$_POST['login']);
    $query->bind('psPass',$_POST['pass']);
    $query->bind('psName',$_POST['name']);
    $query->bind('psEmail',$_POST['email']);
    if(!$query->execute())print $query->getError();
    $connection->close()
}
```